# Combining regexp with in, MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

Are there any ways of combining IN with REGEXP. I have this code:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE `name` IN (SELECT `special_name` FROM table_2)
```

But now it shows that my company are using different ends of names (and different length of the ends) in different departments.
Are there any possibilities to do some REGEXP between two different tables? Someting like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE `name` REGEXP (SELECT `special_name` FROM table_2)
```

Thank you for your help!

PS: The solution got no speed-limit. It's about 200-400 rows in each table and should be executed once every week/month.

EDIT:
Here is a very simple way of showing it: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45d61

Comment: Could you provide sample data? I am not sure I understand the setup.

Comment: Does your "ends of names" follow some pattern? f.e. somename_end1, somename_end2 (I assume that end of name is like "_someend" and you need the "somename" part)

Comment: No, it doesn't have any pattern unfourtunatley.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to reconstruct your regex:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table_1 
WHERE 
  `name` 
  REGEXP 
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`special_name` SEPARATOR '|') FROM table_2)
```

This will work, as, for instance:

```
mysql> SELECT 'fooo' REGEXP 'foo|bar';
+-------------------------+
| 'fooo' REGEXP 'foo|bar' |
+-------------------------+
|                       1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But, this will have limitation because `GROUP_CONCAT()` may not exceed [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) - so either adjust your server option or limit your input data according to it.

**As a side note**: solution like this is:

- Won't work if your strings contain special characters for regex (in this case, you'll have to perform escaping in application, for instance)
- Completely non-scalable. What if you'll want to have 10.000 substrings to search? Or else, 10.000.000?
- Really slow. You'll do all the search one-by-one through all the table. You may end in the situation when one week isn't enough to perform the query.

**Right way**: either implement the logic on the application side, or use search engine like [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com) (if such kind of search is really the intention and not the consequence of bad application design)

Comment: Of course it's bad application design.. Owning more than one external tool for handling more or less the same kinds of data-keys is never a good idea.
Is there anyway to edit group_concat_max_len from PHP and then change it back to the orginal value? (in that way I could actually make it a little bit scalable, even though not to 10.000 substrings)
Now I get the error: `Got error 'parentheses not balanced' from regexp` which I guess is that I haven't changed max_len yet.

Comment: Yes, I've added a sidenote about this limitation. Your solution to this is: use application for constructing regex, so escape all characters there firstly (sane way), or use `REPLACE()` MySQL function and replace all possible regex-specific symbols before applying regex

Comment: To be sure you're not messing up existing alterations: `SELECT '(?:' + GROUP_CONCAT(special_name SEPARATOR ')|(?:') + ')' FROM table_2` :)

Comment: No, it's not needed since OP wants substrings to match even for different words endings, for instance

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to check the start of a string you can use `LIKE` and `%` operators:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 
WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE table_2.special_name LIKE CONCAT(table_1.name , '%'))
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/?bcsi-ac-e7ec86c04da68444=22E8BFED00000503CbExbpdfTc24c69cAMMnob0bZALzAgAAAwUAAPKCwQAIBwAAxQAAAM5qBgA=;bcsi-ac-95bb4efa6a1646c8=22E9FA9100000503VoKWpGHlTkw7H49al2nryMw%20SIPkAgAAAwUAAImFwQAIBwAA5AAAAHDjCwA=#!2/45d61/4/0)